# pytest python test a class method which updates attribute

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

I am quite new to the testing world.

I have a class like the one below.

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self.is_available = False
        # ...
    
    def _try(self, x):
        # do something with x
        # make some network calls

        if some_condition:
             self.is_available = True
        
        return self.is_available

   def find(self, x):
       try:
           self._try(x)
       except:
            pass
        
        # some more code
            
        return self.is_available
```

I want to test the method `find` below. Note that `find` calls another protected method which updates an attribute of the object based on some condition. The same attribute is returned by the `find` method. This is what I have.

```py
class TestX:    
    def test_successful_find(self, mocker):  
        mocker.patch.object(X, "_try", return_value=True)         
        obj = X()  
        # mocker.patch.object(obj, "is_available", True)
        assert obj.find("something") is True
```

Without the commented line in the test, my test fails and un-commenting the same feels like I am setting everything and not actually *testing* anything.

How do I test this?

Comment: What behavior exactly are you trying to test? It looks like you should be mocking out the network calls in `_try`, so you can demonstrate that, "if the network calls are successful we set `self.is_available` to `True`"...but to do that you may need to re-architect your class to make it more testable.